# Error - React Native CI - Azure DevOps - Gulp

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to use Azure DevOps for a React Native app. I'm using gulp to generate an Android App which already has the signing-configs ready and I don't have any problem with it.

**My error in Azure DevOps is:**

[image: Azure DevOps Error]

And my .yml file has the following tasks:

> 1. Install Node 8.16.0
> 2. npm install
> 3. Using gulp task to generate the APK

My CI fails at the 3rd step. I googled so many kinds of stuff, all say to check the Node version which should be greater than 6 as you see I'm already on 8.

So far I tried the below three steps and nothing worked for me.

> 1. Installing @react-native-community/cli as a dev dependency or
>       globally.
> 2. Installing gulp globally or as a dev dependency
> 3. Generating package.json without lock file and ignoring optional dependencies.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: The error indicated "syntax error:missing ) after argument list", have you checked the argument?

Comment: The syntax is correct, it's just an async function. Node 6 doesn't support async function that's why it's throwing an error. I was able to solve it by updating the macOS Version will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue for now by upgrading to the latest vmImage.

Changing this

```
vmImage: 'macOS-latest' #This is macOS Mojave
```

to

```
vmImage: 'macOS-10.15' #This is macOS Catalina
```

solved my problem